# show alertdialog box for disabling gps when stop using the app

Tags: android

I have an application which uses GPS and in the activity that the user takes action ,when pressing the "Get location" button ,it appears an alertdialog and from there the user enables the GPS.

But, when I exit the app or when I exit that activity I want to be able to disable the app.

I read that I must override the onPause method but nothing happens when I press the back arrow or when  I press the home button.

```
GPSTracker gps;
protected LocationManager locationManager;
boolean isGPSEnabled = true;
boolean isNetworkEnabled = true;

@Override
public void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

    try{
    locationManager = (LocationManager) this
           .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

    // getting GPS status
   isGPSEnabled = locationManager
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    // getting network status
    isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

    if (isGPSEnabled && isNetworkEnabled) {
        gps.showSettingsAlertDisable();

    }

    }catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}


public void showSettingsAlertDisable(){
        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

        // Setting Dialog Title
        alertDialog.setTitle("GPS settings");

        // Setting Dialog Message
        alertDialog.setMessage("Do you want to disable GPS?");

        // On pressing Settings button
        alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {

                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
                mContext.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

        // on pressing cancel button
        alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        // Showing Alert Message
        alertDialog.show();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add your code to onBackPressed() or finish()

```
@Override
public void finish() {
  if(!isCalledFromAlertDialog) {
    // Show Alert Dialog - In onClickListener() set variable 
    // isCalledFromAlertDialog to true and call finish()
    // Don't call super.finish();

    final AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setPositiveButton(YES,
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        isCalledFromAlertDialog = true;
                        finish();
                    }
                });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();

    return;
  }
 super.finish();
}
```

Moving code to activity would be better option else you would need to send some message to from service to notify activity about the action.

Comment: :Still , nothing happens. When you say finish how exactly may I implement it?

Comment: :I don't understand the if statement...The way I have it above?

Comment: Actually to show dialog box from you activity, your calling activity should not close. Hence to avoid it, we simply intercept the call to system by not calling super.finish(). But this means that whenever you try to close the activity, dialog box will pop up and activity will never close. Hence I added a flag variable which you should set true in showSettingsAlertDisable - Dialog Box Confirmation Button and call finish(). Hence when user presses OK on your dialog box, call to finsih() with flag variable set to true will make call go to system and thus activity will finish.

Comment: :I added in my post the showSettingsAlertDisable which is in a Service.I can't understand hoe to implement the showSettingsAlertDisable with isCalledFromAlertDialog and finish.

Comment: :I receive a nullpointer exception in " if(gps.showSettingsAlertDisable())".Also,above in the function you have retutn true after mContext.startActivity(intent);But is wrong , right?I put it in the end .

Comment: Yes it should be outside. But this won't work either. I missed the flow while writing. Can't you move this code from service to Activity itself since it doesn't use any service method or variable? else you will need to use some mechanism to notify activity about it.

Comment: @:Ok, I moved it to my mainactivity and run . But now it crashes when i press back button "android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token null is not for an application" in the line if(showSettingsAlertDisable())

Comment: Can you post the code? Since I tried the my code, and it worked for me.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29418/discussion-between-george-and-anirudh)

Comment: :It seems we have a problem..It doesn't make a check if the GPS is enabled or not.It always prompt the user to disable GPS..

Comment: youl need to move code for conditional checks u had in onPause () as well to finish()